# How to share windows folder on internet

Tags: windows-10, port-forwarding, nas, file-sharing, smb

Is there any way to share windows folder from one pc to other over internet. Like we can share folder on same network by going to properties of that folder and then enable sharing an then on other pc on same network there we can open by entering \\ ip\foldername.
Is there any way to do same over internet

Comment: Much safer to use a service like DropBox to share files.

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically it's completely possible – SMB only requires standard TCP/IP communications (over TCP port 445 in all modern versions).

In practice though it's *really* not recommended:

- The Windows built-in SMB server has been a prime target for attacks and exploits in the past. (Samba on Linux might fare somewhat better.)
- The ability for Windows to transparently act as a SMB *client* has been often misused for NTLM credential stealing, by tricking computers into connecting to a malicious server.
- Because of the two above reasons, many networks just completely block the SMB port on their firewall. (Windows does not allow using an alternate port for SMB.)
- In addition, older protocol versions such as SMBv1 and SMBv2 were completely unencrypted – they would transfer your file contents in plain view – and the new encryption feature in SMBv3 doesn't seem like it protects everything either. (Specifically, it seems to offer no protection for the initial login handshake, so NTLM credentials can be snooped on anyway.)
- SMB-over-QUIC promises to solve at least some of those problems, but hasn't been released yet.

So you could use SMB, yes, but you'd need to connect to your home network using a VPN for it to actually be safe. (I don't mean commercial VPNs, but rather a personal VPN service that only connects to your home, or wherever your file server is placed.)

Alternatively, SFTP (the SSH file transfer protocol) is probably your next best option, as Windows now includes a built-in SFTP server (OpenSSH) and there are third-party clients which can present a SFTP connection as a network drive letter (WinFsp sshfs-win, Dokan sshfs).

(There is one other alternative: WebDAV, an HTTP-based folder sharing protocol. Whenever you access a UNC path like '\host\share', Windows tries SMB first, but if that doesn't work it tries using WebDAV instead. The problem though is that installing a WebDAV server – be it IIS or Apache httpd – can get much more complex than one would like. And unfortunately, when used this way, WebDAV is *still* plain-text – there's no way to request HTTPS when accessing an UNC path.)

Comment: I can use ftp but it doesn't allow to live edit file like i have to download the file edit it then upload. What if i turn off firewall ,there is no important data as it is a virtual machine and i required for 30 min per day.

Comment: Samba is just as vulnerable if it's using SMB.  The proper way to connect to any SMB compatible server is through the use of a VPN.  This resolves the majority of the problems with SMB.  A VPN should also be used to connect to a WebDAV server.

Comment: @Ramhound: Not sure why you're saying that. Bugs like buffer overflows are inherently specific to the implementation; just like an exploit against Apache generally won't work against Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid sending SMB/CIFS over the Internet. It will work, but it's a complex protocol (at least compared to HTTP(S)) and some firewalls may have problems supporting it correctly.

I recommend using WebDAV. This is a pretty standard protocol nowadays and is supported by most document management systems (including SharePoint, but also open source systems like [Alfresco](https://www.alfresco.com/)).

For safety reasons you should avoid using unencrypted HTTP, so make sure to use HTTPS.

To access HTTPS WebDAV from Windows explorer just use the UNC path in the following format:

```
\\server@SSL\DavWWWRoot\path\
```

or if the port is different from the standard port 443:

```
\\server@SSL@port\DavWWWRoot\path\
```

Comment: Does web dav allow live editing of file. I dont want to download then edit then upload the file.

Comment: @Aakash: Live editing is not a property of the protocol -- it's a property of the _client_ you're using to connect to that protocol. The Windows built-in client allows this for all protocols; that's the whole point of supporting it through UNC paths. (Although behind the scenes, download/upload is unavoidable no matter what protocol you use... with some clients you just don't need to do it manually because the client does it for you.)

Comment: Like @user1686 said it's up to the client. Some simple applications may not support it, but for example all of the Microsoft Office applications support it for example.